# How to display a value in a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox containing all the countries in the world.
My question is how do I make so "England" is shown on the combobox when the program starts.

I know I can get the index of a country with the code below but don't know how to display the selected country.

```
int index = cmbCountry.Items.IndexOf(address.Country);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cmbCountry.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Comment: this assumes you already have the index obtained like you did in the question.  If you don't need the index, Carlos' answer would work just as easily, selecting it by value.

Answer (score 2):

```
cmbCountry.SelectedValue = "England";
```